# I can not connect to my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, virtual-machines

I have a question. I need to connect a virtual machine Windows 7 32-bit to a domain in Azure. It was created, available and principal. 
The idea is create a domain to connect all PCs that we want. To test it I created a Virtual Machine and I m trying to connect to my domain.
The problem is when I try to connect I have the problem that I show you in the image.

DNS name does not exist

[image]

Comment: Hi, We need much more information here, where is your DC? is it in Azure is it on premise? what type of connection do you have between Azure and your on premise environment? is the DC and the Windows 7 workstation in Azure?

Comment: What hypervisor are you using?  Where is the hypervisor, in Azure or out?  Does the hypervisor have a bridge out of wherever it is?   Is the DC a VM or physical?  Is it on the same network as the Win7 client?  You've assumed too many things, and left them out, making it impossible for anyone to approach answering your question.  Also *It was created, available and principal.*  What does principal mean in this usage?

Comment: The network icon tells us you have internet connectivity.  That leaves determining whether there is a route from the VM to the DC, and determining whether you can resolve domain name into an IP.  The most likely issue here is that your VM cannot resolve the DC by name.

Comment: You might need to use this instead:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-conditional-access-automatic-device-registration-windows7/

Answer (score 0):

first you need to verify that you're using a bridge connection and you're getting a valid ip address, verify that you can ping the domain with its hostname from within the client, if not then you need to register it in your dns server

Answer (score 0):

First check the ping, whether they are able to communicate with each other.  If that fails, then check firewall settings.

Possible reasons:- 
(1) File and Print Sharing must be disabled.  Enable it in Firewall by selecting appropriate profile. (Domain, Public and Private)

(2) IPSec (Internet Protocol Security) must be enabled either with pre-shared key or IPSec Certificate.   You've to find out that.

(3) VMs have their own DHCP Servers and your Windows 7 client must have obtained IP from them.  You can personalize built-in DHCP Server or simply can disable it.

(4) Check with NAT, if you are using bridge.

(5) If none of the above options have to do with issue.  Try changing LAN cards.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the LAN card icon looks to have been connected to internet and makes us believe to have received valid IP  address from DHCP.   I truly believe this must be APIPA (169.254.1.X) that's why the Client is not connecting to domain.